# Convert png image fingerprint to minutiae xyt fingerprint format

Tags: image-processing, fingerprint

I am following Minutiae cylinder code paper and it uses ISO19794-2 or xyt format for minutiae. I tried NIST BIOMDI and NBIS. Both didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mindtct` distributed with [NBIS](https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/nist-biometric-image-software-nbis).

```
$ ./bin/mindtct -b ./sd09/vol_01/sd09/vol_01/crd_0000f/crd_0000f_01.png ./outf
```

Will generate a bunch of files including `./outf.xyt`.